# How can we stop vuetify 3 v-combobox from adding new items if the validation checks fail?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have tried using the `validation-on`, `rules` props, they are able to validate and give me error messages but the new items are still getting appended to the state. Is there any way to change this behaviour so that every time there is a validation error it don't append the item to the state?

#### ParentComponent.vue

```html
...
 <MultiSelect
    v-model="form.tags"
    label="Select Tags"
    :items="tags"
    item-title="name"
    item-value="id"
  />
...
```

#### MultiselectComponent.vue

```html
<template>
    <v-combobox 
        multiple 
    chips 
        closable-chips 
        clearable 
        :return-object="false"
        variant="outlined"
    />
</template>
```

#### What I want

Basically I don't want user to add tags that starts with a number or are all numbers

> e.g. `123`, `2VueJs`, `456890`, `68yjkk` etc.

Comment: I think you should use "rules" for validation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#props-rules

Comment: It was working when I used the vuetify validations but i was facing the problem that even after validation failed my item was still being inserted into the state.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think Moritz Ringler answered to that question then. You need to filter ("validate") the values on insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation is used to show error messages to the user and prevent the form from being submitted. But if you remove invalid values immediately, there is no error message and the values are always going to be valid.

So instead of validation, you can just filter the values coming out of the component. Just replace the `v-model` with the underlying `:modelValue` and `@update:modelValue` and pipe the values through a filter:

```html
<v-combobox
  :model-value="values"
  @update:model-value="values = filterInvalid($event)"
  ...
/>
```

You can also use the filter on the input of `:modelValue` to filter any invalid values coming in, depending on if there are preset values and how to deal with them if they are invalid.

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    return {
      values: ref([12, '12n','n']),
      filterInvalid: (inputValues) => inputValues.filter(value => typeof value === 'string' && isNaN(value[0]))
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="pa-8">
    
      <v-combobox
        :model-value="filterInvalid(values)"
        @update:model-value="values = filterInvalid($event)"
        multiple
        chips
        closable-chips
        clearable
        variant="outlined"
      ></v-combobox>
      
      <div>Values: {{values}}</div>
      
      </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Note however that removing values automatically can feel like a bug to users. You might be better off with the validation approach after all.

Comment: How can I make the multiple chips combobox to stop inserting new tags to the state but still allow to select multiple tags from the dropdown?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - what is "state"? If you don't want to add new tags at all, that's a select, not a combobox. If you want to use the dropdown, you need to use the [`:items`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#props-items) prop. But neither has anything to do with prohibiting certain input, which is what you were asking for, right? Am I missing something?